# Searching for 3D photo gallery (HTML5 or Flash)

Tags: javascript, html, flash, 3d

I need 3D gallery writen on Flash/HTML5. Something like [this](http://www.brafa.be/media/brafa/01/flash/virtual_tour/2013/brafa.html) or [this](http://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/collection/real-academia-de-bellas-artes-de-san-fernando?museumview&projectId=art-project)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom google street view landscape, based on the content for your 3D gallery.

The API looks fairly simple to follow: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview?hl#CustomStreetView